# Compile with angular 8 instead of the 9

Tags: angular8, angular9

I recently installed Angular 9. I would like to experiment by trying to compile my project with Angular 8.
Is it possible to choose the version with which to compile? Since I previously had Angular 8? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your tsconfig.json file, add:

```
{
"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "enableIvy": false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also have this issues before few days i got the error something like "my angular version is 8.0.2 but my angular cli is 9.0" so that it will not able to compile the code.

**Then i change the whole project in angular 9**
  I also try with changing the version name or all but it not works.